# Titulo na url com codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Pesquisei em vários lugares como passar o titulo de um post na url usando o codeigniter, 
ex: http://sirc/filmes/listar/clube-da-luta
A unica forma que consegui ate agora foi usar o Helper `url_title()`, porem na hora de pesquisar no banco da erro pois não existe o titulo clube-da-luta, e sim Clube da Luta.
Então vi que deveria criar um campo no banco para conter a slug do post para ser usada na pesquisa.

Queria saber se existe outra forma de fazer isso sem ter que mexer no banco, usando `url_title()` ou outra função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o melhor mesmo seja criar outro campo com o slug "clube-da-luta". Assim sempre encontrará o resultado correto, desde que você limite não ter 2 registros com o mesmo slug.

Esta solução funcionará também quando você tiver caracteres especiais. Exemplo:

**Nome:**
Temperatura Máxima

**Slug:**
temperatura-maxima ou temperatura-mxima (se tirar os caracteres especiais).

Sem a referência "de/para" seria muito difícil encontrar o registro correto, pois a slug se quer tem todos os caractéres.

Se você simplesmente substituir o hífen por branco, funcionará em situações muito específicas e aconteceria outro problema. Por exemplo, quando o nome original do filme tiver hífen:

**Nome:**
Star-Wars: O despertar da força

**Slug:**
star-wars-o-despertar-da-forca

Se procurar por "star wars o despertar da forca" no banco não irá encontrar.

Comment: Realmente nesses casos com hífen ou mesmo com subtitulo separado por dois pontos não daria certo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função (PHP) [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) para retirar os hifens da slug.

```
$filme = 'clube-da-luta';
str_replace('-', ' ', $filme);
//Resultado: clube da luta
```

Para formatar o texto, você pode usar [ucfirst()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ucfirst.php) ou [ucwords()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ucwords.php).